# udev systemd call @remove does not work but triggers scripts openSuse Leap42.3

Tags: systemd, udev, unmounting

Hi I have an UDEV rule that calls a systemd Service that umounts my USB Drive when it is removed.

```
ACTION=="remove", KERNEL=="sd*" SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ATTRS{idVendor}=="XXXX", ATTRS{idProduct}=="XXXX", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="umount_extern_backup.service"
```

The problem is that the systemd service gets not executed if I physically unplug my USB Drive.

If I use the same UDEV rule

```
ACTION=="remove", KERNEL=="sd*" SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ATTRS{idVendor}=="XXXX", ATTRS{idProduct}=="XXXX", RUN+="/bin/umount -l /extern-backup"
```

to directly execute `/bin/umount -l /extern-backup` the command gets executed but I receive an error:
`udevd[10181]: Process '/bin/umount -l /extern-backup' failed with exit code 32.` That is why I try to execute a systemd service because then the umount command works.

If I change the UDEV rule to execute a shell script it works:

```
ACTION=="remove", KERNEL=="sd*" SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ATTRS{idVendor}=="XXXX", ATTRS{idProduct}=="XXXX", RUN+="/usr/local/sbin/test.sh"
```

The test.sh gets executed. But I cannot directly use a shell script called by UDEV to execute the `umount` command because it gives me the same error as executing `/bin/umount -l /extern-backup` directly from UDEV.

If I call `systemctl start umount_extern_backup.service` manually the service also works.

To add the Icing on the cake if I replace `ACTION=="remove"` with `ACTION=="add",` for the UDEV rule then the systemd service gets executed and tries to umount when I connect my USB device.

Here is my systemd service:

```
[Unit]
Description=umount lazy /extern-backup service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=no
ExecStart=/bin/umount -l /extern-backup

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: What happens when you configure your UDEV rule with RUN+="/usr/bin/systemctl umount_extern_backup.service" ?

Answer (score 2):

`RUN+="/usr/bin/systemctl umount_extern_backup.service"` as mentioned in a comment above works.

I checked `SYSTEMD_WANTS` device property [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.device.html) and they write:

> Note that systemd will only act on Wants dependencies when a device
>   **first becomes active**. It will not act on them if they are added to devices that are already active

This explains why the `add` rule triggered the systemd service and the `remove` rule not.